# Example of a homeomorphism that is not a diffeomorphism between two diffeomorphic surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, surfaces, diffeomorphism

Give an example of a homeomorphism that is not a diffeomorphism between two diffeomorphic surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The only function that came in my mind is $(x,y) \mapsto (x^3, y^3, \sqrt{1-x^6-y^6})$ between the two surfaces $\{(x,y) \mid x^6 + y^6 < 1\}$ and the image of the function (that I think is $S^2 \cap \{z > 0\}$). Some help? Thanks.

Comment: Your set, as you've written it, lives in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Probably, you intend the open [squircular](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Squircle) disk embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e. $\{(x, y, 0) \mid x^6 + y^6 < 1\}$.

Comment: yes, i mean that sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the surfaces $S=S^*=\{(x,y,0)\mid x,y\in\Bbb R\}$. And then consider$$\begin{array}{ccc}S&\longrightarrow&S^*\\(x,y,0)&\mapsto&(x^3,y,0),\end{array}$$which is a homeomorphism, but not a diffeomorphism.